# Loading group of elements attributes as an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on this demo code. How can I modify the code to get array of array in the `data[]` from the attributes of each `.box`?

```js
let data = [];
$(".box").each(function(){
    data.push($(this).data('color'), $(this).data('size'));

});
console.log(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box" data-color="red" data-size="large"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="white" data-size="large"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="green" data-size="medium"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="yellow" data-size="small"></div>
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: `data.push([$(this).data('color'), $(this).data('size')]);` you aren't pushing an array into the array, you're pushing two single elements. wrap arguments with an array to push the attributes as an array, assuming that is what you were expecting. also, you can use `const` for declaring arrays and objects, and you will still be able to modify them, you just can't reassign the variable.

Comment: @r3wt you should post that as an answer. I'd suggest using `map()` instead of `each()` as well

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan does jQuery even have `.map()`??? i haven't used jQuery in ages. **EDIT:** damn, it does and has for a long time. i feel old

Answer (score 1):

As suggested on commentaries, you need to wrap the data you are pushing into an array, as explained by **@r3wt**. However, maybe an array of objects is better suit in the case you have multiples properties:

```js
let arrayOfData = [...$(".box")].map(
    box => ({
        color: $(box).data('color'),
        size: $(box).data('size'),
        category: $(box).data('category')
    })
);

console.log(arrayOfData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box" data-color="red" data-size="large" data-category="short"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="white" data-size="large" data-category="t-shirt"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="green" data-size="medium" data-category="shoes"></div>
<div class="box" data-color="yellow" data-size="small" data-category="short"></div>
```